# Affine conics over an algebraically closed field of char 2

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following argument classifies affine conics over an algebraically closed field $k$ with char$(k)\neq 2.$

But I don't see where it uses the hypothesis that char$(k)\neq 2.$ Is it an unnecessary hypothesis?

---

---

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field with char$(k)\neq2$ and let $Q(x,y)$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree 2 in $k[x,y].$

We write $Q(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f$ for some $a,\ldots,f \in k.$

Since $k$ is algebraically closed, we have
$$Q(x,y)=L_1L_2+L_3+f$$
where $L_3=dx+ef$ and $L_1,L_2$ are linear forms in $k[x,y]$ such that $L_1L_2=ax^2+bxy+cy^2.$

We split into two cases: (1) $L_1\sim L_2$ and  (2) $L_1\not\sim L_2.$

---

(1) If $L_1\sim L_2,$ then $L_2=\lambda L_1$ for some $\lambda \in k^\times$ and we have $Q(x,y)=\lambda L_1^2 + L_3 + f.$

Since $k$ is algebraically closed and $Q(x,y)$ is irreducible in $k[x,y],$ it follows that $L_1\not\sim L_3.$

Therefore $(u,v)=(\sqrt{-\lambda}L_1,\,L_3+f)$ is an affine change of coordinates such that 
$$Q(x,y)=v-u^2.$$

(2) If $L_1\not\sim L_2,$ then there exist $\lambda,\mu \in k$ such that $L_3=\lambda L_1+\mu L_2.$

As such, we have $Q(x,y)=(L_1+\mu)(L_2+\lambda)-(\lambda\mu-f).$

Since $Q(x,y)$ is irreducible in $k[x,y],$ it follows that $\lambda\mu-f\neq 0.$

Therefore $(u,v)=\left(\dfrac{L_1+\mu}{\sqrt{\lambda\mu-f}}\,,\dfrac{L_2+\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda\mu-f}}\right)$ is an affine change of coordinates such that 
$$Q(x,y)\sim uv-1.$$

---

If $L_1=\alpha x+ \beta y$ and $L_2=\gamma x + \delta y,$ then $L_1\sim L_2$ if and only if $\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma=0.$

Moreover, since $L_1L_2=ax^2+bxy+cy^2,$ we have
$$(\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma)^2=(\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma)^2-4(\alpha\gamma)(\beta\delta)=b^2-4ac.$$
It thus follows that
$$k[x,y]/(Q(x,y))\cong \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
k[t] & \text{if } b^2=4ac,\\
k[t,t^{-1}] & \text{if } b^2\neq 4ac.
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: I don't see any issue, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532289/conics-over-fields-of-characteristic-two) of Takumi Murayama crafted for the express purpose of the characteristic two case agrees with it.

Comment: OK thanks! So, just to confirm, we don’t actually need char(k) not equal to 2 for this argument then?

Comment: As far as I can tell, every step here is valid in every characteristic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my comment in to an answer:

Here are some lemmas used in the proof. All of these are true no matter the characteristic of the field.

**Lemma 1**: Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Then any polynomial in one variable over $k$ factors completely in to a product of (not necessarily distinct) linear factors.

Proof: This is the definition of $k$ being algebraically closed.

**Lemma 2**: Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Then any homogeneous polynomial in two variables over $k$ factors completely in to (not necessarily distinct) homogeneous linear factors.

Proof: Let $f(x,y)$ be our polynomial. Write $f(x,y)=x^ng(x,y)$ with $n$ maximal. Now $g(x,y)$ is not divisible by $x$. If $g=1$, we are done. If not, then dehomogenize $g$ with respect to $x$, apply lemma 1, and rehomogenize to get the result.

**Lemma 3**: A linear endomorphism of $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ given by $x_i\mapsto \sum a_{ij}x_j$ is an automorphism iff the matrix $[a_{ij}]$ is invertible.

Proof: The inverse transformation is given by the inverse of the above matrix, and composing the transformations corresponds to multiplying matrices.

**Lemma 4**: An affine endomorphism of $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ given by $x_i\mapsto \sum a_{ij}x_j + c_i$ is an automorphism iff the matrix $[a_{ij}]$ is invertible.

Proof: It's enough to show that every translation $x_i\mapsto x_i+c_i$ is an endomorphism, as the composition of endomorphisms are endomorphisms, and the linear portion is taken care of by lemma 3. But this is clear, as the inverse of a translation $x_i\mapsto x_i+c_i$ is $x_i\mapsto x_i-c_i$.

---

We factor $f=L_1L_2+L_3+c$ by lemma 2 applied to the degree two portion.

In case 1, we see that $L_3\not \sim L_1$ otherwise $f=p(L_1)$ for some quadratic $p\in k[t]$, which would imply it must be reducible by lemma 1. The stated affine coordinate change is then an isomorphism because the determinant of the relevant matrix mentioned in lemma 4 is $\sqrt{-\lambda}\neq 0$.

In case 2, we note that the first claim about writing $L_3$ as a linear combination of $L_1=Ax+By$ and $L_2=Cx+Dy$ follows from the fact that the vectors $(A,B)$ and $(C,D)$ are linearly independent - $L_1\not\sim L_2$ iff $\det\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix} \neq0$, so this means we can write $L_3=Ex+Fy$ as the desired linear combination. We then apply lemma 4.

In the final statement, it is clear that characteristic two is never used, and the classification exactly matches that of the [fine answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532289/conics-over-fields-of-characteristic-two) of Takumi Murayama written expressly for the characteristic two case.

Thus the proof detailed in the question is valid in any characteristic.

Comment: Lovely! Thank you